# Searching if an array of strings contain an array if char's

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, full-text-search, text-files

Currently fiddling with a little project I'm working on, it's a count down type game (the tv show).
Currently, the program allows the user to pick a vowel or consonant to a limit of 9 letters and then asks them to input the longest word they can think of using these 9 letters.

I have a large text file acting as a dictionary that i search through using the user inputted string to try match a result to check if the word they entered is a valid word. My problem, is that I want to then search my dictionary for the longest word made up of the nine letters, but i just cant seem to find a way to implement it.

So far I've tried putting every word into an array and searching through each element to check if it contains the letters but this wont cover me if the longest word that can be made out of the 9 letters is a 8 letter word. Any idea's?
Currently I have this (This is under the submit button on the form, sorry for not providing code or mentioning it's a windows form application):

```
StreamReader textFile = new StreamReader("C:/Eclipse/Personal Projects/Local_Projects/Projects/CountDown/WindowsFormsApplication1/wordlist.txt");
int counter1 = 0;
String letterlist = (txtLetter1.Text + txtLetter2.Text + txtLetter3.Text + txtLetter4.Text + txtLetter5.Text + txtLetter6.Text + txtLetter7.Text + txtLetter8.Text + txtLetter9.Text); // stores the letters into a string
char[] letters = letterlist.ToCharArray(); // reads the letters into a char array
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines("C:/Eclipse/Personal Projects/Local_Projects/Projects/CountDown/WindowsFormsApplication1/wordlist.txt"); // reads every line in the word file into a string array (there is a new word on everyline, and theres 144k words, i assume this will be a big performance hit but i've never done anything like this before so im not sure ?)

line.Any(x => line.Contains(x)); // just playing with linq, i've no idea what im doing though as i've never used before
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)// a loop that loops for every word in the  string array
//  if (line.Contains(letters)) //checks if a word contains the letters in the char array(this is where it gets hazy if i went this way, i'd planned on only using words witha  letter length > 4, adding any words found to another text file and either finding the longest word then in this text file or keeping a running longest word i.e.  while looping i find a word with 7 letters, this is now the longest word, i then go to the next word and it has 8 of our letters, i now set the longest word to this)

counter1++;
if (counter1 > 4)
```

txtLongest.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;

Mike's code:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var letters = args[0];

    var wordList = new List<string> { "abcbca", "bca", "def" }; // dictionary

    var results = from string word in wordList // makes every word in dictionary into a seperate string
                  where IsValidAnswer(word, letters) // calls isvalid method
                  orderby word.Length descending // sorts the word with most letters to top
                  select word; // selects that word

    foreach (var result in results) {
        Console.WriteLine(result);    //  outputs the word
    }
}

private static bool IsValidAnswer(string word, string letters) {
    foreach (var letter in word) {
        if (letters.IndexOf(letter) == -1) { // checks if theres letters in the word
            return false;
        }

        letters = letters.Remove(letters.IndexOf(letter), 1);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: To Adrian's point, it helps to post the code you wrote so we know where to start.

Comment: This sounds like a NP hard problem, if I understand you correctly. There is (presumably) no simple way of doing this. Have a look at the [coin-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: Can you reuse characters? If you chose a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i - can you spell `egg`?, or should you chose `g` twice in order to do so?

Comment: @amit you can't reuse letters - think of it as being like scrabble but purely about getting the longest word from the given letters.  for example AEHLLOWPQ contains "hello" and "whale" where AEHLMOWPQ does not contain "hello" because L cannot be reused.

Comment: This would make quite a good coding homework project if there are any tutors/teachers watching.  :)

Comment: @mike i like the look of your idea, but im not sure if i understand it 100% , i think i do though and have commented your's it's too long to add in a comment though so ill add it onto my question and could you correct it where i've commented wrong? ps. how does linq work with different variable types eg strings chars etc? do i need to worry about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer I knocked together in a couple of minutes which should do what you want.  As others have said, this problem is complex and so the algorithm is going to be slow.  The LINQ query evaluates each string in the dictionary, checking whether the supplied letters can be used to produce said word.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var letters = args[0];

        var wordList = new List<string> { "abcbca", "bca", "def" };

        var results = from string word in wordList
                      where IsValidAnswer(word, letters)
                      orderby word.Length descending
                      select word;

        foreach (var result in results) {
            Console.WriteLine(result);    
        }
    }

    private static bool IsValidAnswer(string word, string letters) {
        foreach (var letter in word) {
            if (letters.IndexOf(letter) == -1) {
                return false;
            }

            letters = letters.Remove(letters.IndexOf(letter), 1);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So where are you getting stuck? Start with the slow brute-force method and just find all the words that contain all the characters. Then order the words by length to get the longest. If you don't want to return a word that is shorter than the number of characters being sought (which I guess is only an issue if there are duplicate characters???), then add a test and eliminate that case.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some more thoughts about this. I think the way to do it efficiently is by preprocessing the dictionary, ordering the letters in each word in alphabetical order and ordering the words in the list alphabetically too (you'll probably have to use some sort of multimap structure to store the original word and the sorted word).

Once you've done that you can much more efficiently find the words that can be generated from your pool of letters. I'll come back and flesh out an algorithm for doing this later, if someone else doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Construct a trie structure with each word sort by letter.

Example: EACH is sorted to ACEH is stored as A->C->E->H->(EACH, ACHE, ..) in the trie (ACHE is an anagram of EACH).

Step 2: Sort the input letters and find find the longest word corresponding to that set of letters in the trie.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried implementing something like this? It would be great to see your code you have tried.

```
string[] strArray = {"ABCDEFG", "HIJKLMNOP"};
string findThisString = "JKL";
int strNumber;
int strIndex = 0;
for (strNumber = 0; strNumber < strArray.Length; strNumber++)
{
    strIndex = strArray[strNumber].IndexOf(findThisString);
    if (strIndex >= 0)
        break;
}
System.Console.WriteLine("String number: {0}\nString index: {1}",
    strNumber, strIndex);
```

Comment: How does it solves the problem? How will it find the word "LKJ" if it is in there? How can it find the **longest word** that can be constructed using the characters. Please explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

This must do the job :

```
private static void Main()
{
    char[] picked_char = {'r', 'a', 'j'};
    string[] dictionary = new[] {"rajan", "rajm", "rajnujaman", "rahim", "ranjan"};
    var words = dictionary.Where(word => picked_char.All(word.Contains)).OrderByDescending(word => word.Length);


    foreach (string needed_words in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(needed_words);
    }
}
```

Output :

---

`rajnujaman`
`ranjan`
`rajan`
`rajm`

Comment: This code does not do the job.  As a test case set picked_char to 'a','a','j','n','n','r','x','y','z' and see what words you get back.